# Multiprocessing and slow file system

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

Let's say that we have the following script (`read_file.py`) that reads a file and writes the top 200000 lines to another file.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]

df = pd.read_csv(a, header=0, sep="\t").head(200000).to_csv(b, header=True, index=False)
```

And let's have a second script (`test-latency.py`) that calls the first script with multiprocessing (on two files). Then reads the two files generated and merges them.

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
import subprocess
import time

a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]

l = [a, b]

pool = mp.Pool(processes = (mp.cpu_count() - 1))
for filename in l:
    f_in = filename
    f_out = filename + "out.tsv"
    cmd = ['python', 'read_file.py', f_in, f_out]
    pool.apply_async(subprocess.Popen, (cmd,))
pool.close()
pool.join()

time.sleep(1)

df1 = pd.read_csv(a + "out.tsv")
df2 = pd.read_csv(b + "out.tsv")

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Name").to_csv("test.tsv", sep="\t", header=0)
```

The problem is that depending on the filesystem speed (due to NFS caching) the files might not be present after pool.join(). This is somehow solved via `time.sleep(1)` that delays until the files are present. But this is not an optimal solution, as for slow filesystem it can lead to a `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]`. One solution is to provide a general latency-wait option, but I don't think it's smart to involve the user on such decisions. What is your recommendation on the issue?

Comment: `tail` reads the bottom lines, not the top ones. You'd want `head` for that.

Comment: File systems are state-based data stores, not event-driven messaging systems.  Don't use them as messaging systems.

Comment: So this is specifically about NFS?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, sorry. I updated the code.

Comment: @Wups It occurred in NFS, but it might be more general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filesystem caching is not your problem. You're creating subprocesses with `multiprocessing.Pool`, and each of those subprocesses is *itself* spawning a subprocess with `subprocess.Popen`. The problem is that `subprocess.Popen` just spawns the process, but does not wait for completion. So even after the child processes from `multiprocessing.Pool` have all finished, these grandchildren might still be running.

A simple fix is to manage the subprocesses yourself:

```py
# Store subprocess handles (Popen objects).
subprocesses = []

# Launch subprocesses in the background.
for filename in l:
    f_in = filename
    f_out = filename + "out.tsv"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'read_file.py', f_in, f_out])
    subprocesses.append(proc)

# Wait for each subprocess to finish.
for proc in subprocesses:
    if proc.wait() != 0:
        # Error occurred, handle it however you want
        raise RuntimeError('Subprocess failed with nonzero exit code')
```

There's also the question of whether it's even useful to do this in parallel, because I/O (either network or disk) is likely to be the bottleneck. But that's something you can test for yourself.